# Status de desenvolvimento do plugin Eclipse Grails-IDE?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, grails, eclipse-plugin, grails-plugin

Entendo que o plugin do Eclipse [Groovy Development Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovy-development-tools) ainda está sendo mantido pelas equipes da Pivotal, pois ontem mesmo uma versão de lançamento foi liberada em 6 de Janeiro de 2020. Infelizmente, esse plugin não fornece suporte ao Grails e os detalhes da visão geral no [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/) afirmam como eu cito:

> GDT does not provide any direct support for Grails. If you want Grails tooling, then please consider [Groovy-Grails Tools Suite](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovygrails-tool-suite-ggts-eclipse) or [spring-projects/grails-ide](https://github.com/spring-projects/grails-ide) for your Grails projects.

**Traduzindo para o português:**

> O GDT não fornece nenhum suporte direto ao Grails. Se você deseja ferramentas Grails, considere o [Groovy-Grails Tools Suite](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovygrails-tool-suite-ggts-eclipse) ou [spring-projects/grails-ide](https://github.com/spring-projects/grails-ide) para seus projetos Grails.

Minha instalação do Eclipse é a mais recente, a 4.14 atualmente, com vários plug-ins que se baseiam nessa mesma versão, como o RedHat Codeready, por exemplo, portanto, fazer o downgrade para o Eclipse Juno e encontrar uma versão compatível para cada um dos plugins que eu uso não é uma opção. Além disso, a compra do IntelliJ não foi autorizada e o NetBeans é de longe o IDE menos usado atualmente para obter ajuda da comunidade.

Dito isto, eu tinha uma última opção que era [spring-projects/grails-ide](https://github.com/spring-projects/grails-ide), mas quando acessei essa URL, descobri que o último commit foi em 20 de Março de 2019, quase um ano atrás, o que me leva a pensar que o a última versão de lançamento não está pronta para o Eclipse 4.14. Além disso, não consigo encontrar a visão geral do plug-in no Eclipse Marketplace.

1. Alguém sabe informações sobre este plugin?
2. Ainda está sendo mantido atualmente? Caso contrário, quais foram as últimas versões do Eclipse e Grails suportadas?
3. Alguém sugere um plugin alternativo para trabalhar com Grails e Eclipse que possua destaque de sintaxe (syntax highlighting), code assist (code completion, intelissence) e que permita usar um compilador grails para ver possíveis problemas de sintaxe na fase de desenvolvimento?

**Não se trata de qual IDE ou plugin é melhor, apenas preciso de orientação, pois não trabalho muito com o Grails há muito tempo e agora chegou a hora de voltar.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o plugin não será mais mantido pela equipe. Há um comentário numa issue do repositório do spring-ide relatando o fato:

> The original team that created grails-ide is not currently working on it but we are happy to help anyone trying to pick up the code and run with it. There is no planned future GGTS distribution release (that is an eclipse distro with grails-ide embedded). We would probably find time to merge pull requests if they were forthcoming.

[Link da Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/grails-ide/issues/7#issuecomment-141535560)

Analisando a árvore de commits, os mais relevantes foram realizados em 2015 e depois disso não houve alterações de grande impacto.

Como sugestão, quero deixar a experiência de mais de 8 anos trabalhando com Grails no Intellij IDEA. É uma plataforma sem comparações e desde então venho mantendo minha licença em dia. Vale cada centavo investido.

Comment: IntelliJ não foi autorizado a comprar a licença, infelizmente.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi procurando aqui sobre outras alternativas, notei que o NetBeans possui suporte ao Grails. Não sei se está atualizado para suportar o Grails 4, mas talvez valha a pena baixar e testar. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/grails-quickstart_pt_BR.html

Comment: Vou até olhar, mas como eu disse na própria questão, o NetBeans hoje quase não é mais utilizado para ter um suporte da comunidade caso necessário, mas com certeza vale olhar sim.